# How to use Azure Event Hub in streamsets?

Tags: azure, streamsets

I have 2 Event hubs in Azure portal. I want to use this Event Hubs in streamsets as a source. I mentioned all configuration but getting following error:

Pipeline Status:

```
RUNNING_ERROR: EVENT_HUB_02 - Failed to connect : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided EventHub path in eventHubPath parameter conflicts with the path in provided EventHub connection string.
```

Can anybody suggest me something?

Comment: Did you check it as per the error states?

Answer (score 1):

You are hitting this exception - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/f9b688989c09882d43eb614e2c2eeaa0f6361951/sdk/eventhubs/microsoft-azure-eventhubs-eph/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/eventprocessorhost/EventProcessorHost.java#L697

Make sure the eventhub name in the connection string is the same as the name provided for EventProcessorHost instance. You can remove the eventhub name from connection string, that should also address the failure.